# Laravel - model for table with only foreign keys (Pivot Table)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I need to implement model for table with only two foreign keys. In my db I have tables like this:

```
product (id_product, ...)
category_to_product (FK id_category, FK id_product)
category (id_category, ...)
```

How to manage this connections in Laravel? Should I implement model for merge table and how it may looks? `category_to_product` table does not represent entity(/model) and have only design-relation property.

[image: database-model]

---

**Database Migrations**

**CategoryToProduct**

```
Schema::create('category_to_product', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('id_category')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('id_category')
          ->references('id_category')
          ->on('categories')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('id_product')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('id_product')
          ->references('id_product')
          ->on('products')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Products**

```
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments('id_product');
  // ...
});
```

**Categories**

```
Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments('id_category');
  // ...
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 eloquent pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550761/laravel-4-eloquent-pivot-table)

Answer (score 3):

@pc-shooter is right about creating methods.

But you still have to create the pivot table with your migration first

```
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id')
    $table->string('name');
}
Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id')
    $table->string('name');
}
```

Then your pivot table

```
Schema::create('category_product', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('category_id')
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

    $table->integer('product_id');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');

    // And finally, the indexes (Better perfs when fetching data on that pivot table)
    $table->index(['category_id', 'product_id'])->unique(); // This index has to be unique
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm already created pivot table and others. But I'm also added `unsigned` because `autoincrement` in laravel and mysql makes field unsigned and `cascade delete` option because without product or category row is meaningless. Also added code to question.

`$table->integer('id_category')->unsigned(); $table->foreign('id_category')->references('id_category')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');`

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

In the model **Category**:

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
}
```

In the model **Product**:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'category_to_product');
}
```

In the model **CategoryToProduct**:

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}

public function products() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
}
```

---

**Note the naming of these methods!
 Those are the same as the DB-table names. See [ChainList](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056512/chainlist)'s
answer.**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. In your example you use `belongsToMany`, but in another examples people used this method with `withPivot` method. When needed `withPivot` method?

Comment: withPivot is needed when you want to manually retrieve informations from your pivot table. (For example, you could have a pivot table with 2 foreign keys and also a third columns called 'retweet'. Without calling the withPivot method you can't access 'retweet' columns.
To do so, simply do the following : Category::where('id', 1)->withPivot()->first()->retweet

Comment: @ChainList You should add this to your answer. It's a nice explaination!